# (Inverse?) Fourier transform for finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, fourier-transform, characters

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_m}$ be a finite abelian group and $C(G)$ the algebra of complex-valued functions on $G$ with pointwise-multiplication. Let a basis be given by:
$$\left\{\delta_{(g_1,\dots,g_m)}\mid(g_1,\dots,g_m)\in G\right\}.$$
Let $\mathbb{C}G$ be the group algebra with basis $\{(g_1,\dots,g_m)\mid (g_1,\dots,g_m)\in G\}$, and multiplication the bilinear extension of the group law.

Let $N=\prod_{j=1}^m n_j$.

Consider the following linear map $C(G)\to \mathbb{C}G$:

$$\delta_{(g_1,\dots,g_m)}\mapsto \frac{1}{N}\sum_{(t_1,\dots,t_m)\in G}\left(\prod_{j=1}^m \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i t_jg_j}{n_j}\right)\right)(t_1,\dots,t_m)\qquad \qquad(\star).$$

Let us call this map $T$. Recalling $T(\delta_{(g_1,\dots,g_m)})\in\mathbb{C}G$, some properties I have, if I am not mistaken, are  (the conjugate-linear involution is $g^\ast=g^{-1}$):

$$T(\delta_{(g_1,\dots,g_m)})=T(\delta_{(g_1,\dots,g_m)})^2=T(\delta_{(g_1,\dots,g_m)})^*.$$

---

Now to say the definition of this map is inspired by Fourier-type ideas is an understatement. The problem is that I have confusion about the correct source and target for the Fourier transform, and the duality between $G$ and its dual is confusing this further. So some references will suggest that $T$ is the Fourier transform while others will suggest it is the inverse... and nowhere have I seen $(\star)$ written down explicitly (when it looks familiar, maybe the $1/N$ is missing). So, some questions:

> Is $(\star)$ written down explicitly anywhere?
>
> Is $T$ a Fourier transform? Is is perhaps a Fourier transform $C(G)\to \mathbb{C}G$ but also the inverse of a different Fourier transform
> $\mathbb{C}G\to C(G)$?
>
> Is there a similarly explicit expression for the inverse of $T$?

It would be nice to have the correct terminology for this map (and also know that it is invertible).

**EDIT:** In addition I want $T:C(G)\to \mathbb{C}G$ and it's inverse to be unital in the sense that, where $\mathbf{1}_G$ maps everything one:
$$T(\mathbf{1}_G)=e\qquad\text{ and}\qquad T^{-1}(e)=\mathbf{1}_G.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $(\star)$ looks very reasonable, but there are many other good choices for it: as you mention, some people normalise by dividing one direction (usually the inverse transform) by $N$, others prefer to put a denominator of $\sqrt{N}$ on both the transform and its inverse. The key choice which is being slid under the rug here is that you have explicitly chosen a set of generators for your group $G$. Someone else might choose a different set of generators and get a different output for the Fourier transform (it would still have all the right properties though). If you'll allow me to delve into some theory for a moment, it may explain the situation.

What's actually going on here is that the Fourier transfom is *naturally* (meaning there are no choices to be made) a linear map $\mathcal{F} \colon C(G) \to C(\hat{G})$, where $\hat{G} = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(G, \mathbb{C}^\times)$ is the *dual group* consisting of all group homomorphisms $G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$, with pointwise multiplication as the group operation. For $G$ finite abelian, we have that $G$ is isomorphic to its dual $\hat{G}$ but not canonically: there are many choices of isomorphisms and none of them is preferred.

An element $\chi \colon G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ of the dual group is usually called a *character*. Given a function $f \in C(G)$ and a character $\chi \in \hat{G}$, we can integrate them against each other:
$$ \int_G f \chi = \sum_{g \in G} f(g) \chi(g).$$
The *Fourier transform* of $f \in C(G)$ is the function $\mathcal{F}f \in C(\hat{G})$ defined by $(\mathcal{F} f)(\chi) = \int_G f \chi$. You can prove that this has all the properties you would expect of something called a Fourier transform (linearity, convolution becomes pointwise product, etc), however it is now a function on the dual group.

There is a natural isomorphism from $G$ to its double dual $\hat{\hat{G}}$, given by $g \mapsto \operatorname{ev}_g$ ("evaluation at $g$"), where $\operatorname{ev}_g(\chi) = \chi(g)$. Using orthogonality of characters it is easily shown that when you take the Fourier transform again, you get $(\mathcal{F} \mathcal{F} f)(\operatorname{ev}_g) = |G| f(g^{-1})$. Therefore the Fourier transform is almost its own inverse: you need to divide by $|G|$ somewhere, and invert or conjugate somewhere. (Compare the usual formulas for the discrete Fourier transform and its inverse: there is a division by $|G|$ and a conjugation).

This is all very well, but often we want to actually do calculations rather than talking about nice coordinate-free formulas, so often we need to choose a particular isomorphism $G \to \hat{G}$. A straightforward way to do this is to do exactly as you have done: pick a set of generators $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ so that $G$ is a product of cyclic groups with orders $n_1, \ldots, n_k$, then define a map $G \to \hat{G}$ by taking the group element $g = m_1 g_1 + \cdots + m_k g_k$ to the character
$$ r_1 g_1 + \cdots + r_k g_k \mapsto \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i m_1 r_1}{n_1}\right) \cdots \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i m_k r_k}{n_k}\right)$$
You can see that under this identification, the formula I've given above for the coordinate-free Fourier transform is almost exactly your $(\star)$, the only difference being a division by $|G|$. To take the inverse transform, all you need to do is add/remove the division by $N$, and conjugate the exponentials.

If you would like to read more, there is ample literature out there about dual groups for finite abelian groups. A lovely extension of this is *Pontryagin duality* which essentially applies Fourier transforms to more groups: for finite cyclic groups you get the DFT, for more general finite groups you get your $(\star)$, for the circle you get the Fourier expansion of a periodic function, and for $\mathbb{R}$ you get the Fourier transform which you might have come across in a differential equations or measure theory course.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer which almost answers my question. I am aware of almost all that you have written: I think the answer to the first question is that ($\star$) is just the multidimensional DFT. I don't think we have answered the second part of the second question... nor the third question.

Your answer is most helpful in the normalisation and has led to an edit of the question.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy No worries - to answer your second question yes, $T$ is a Fourier transform. There is a fair bit of freedom with the exactly formula. The explicit inverse of $T$ is almost the same formula as $T$, just with the division by $N$ removed and a minus sign added into the $\exp(\cdots)$. This was meant to be implicit in the formula $(\mathcal{F} \mathcal{F} f)(\operatorname{ev}_g) = |G| f(g^{-1})$. Of course you could switch which side the division is on and still have a function obeying Fourier transform-like properties.

Comment: There is nobody coming in so it seems you will get the bounty but I am not fully satisfied the questions are answered. To reiterate:

Question: Is $T$ the inverse of a Fourier transform $\mathbb{C}G\to C(G)$?

Question: Is $T$ unital, $\mathbf{1}_G\mapsto e$?

Question: Is there an expression for $T^{-1}$ around?

I think I should be able to answer all of these now all the same.